# General solution of $y''+y = 4\cos x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I know how to find the complementary function of this non-homogenous equation. The complementary function is $y = A \cos x + B \sin x$. But I don't understand how to find the particular solution. If we use $y_p = p \cos x + q \sin x$, where $p$ and $q$ are constants to be determined. This doesn't work out, as the result becomes zero. Please tell the particular integral to find the particular solution.

Comment: First you find the solution of the homogeneous equation.  In this case, $4\cos(x)$ is already a solution of the homogeneous equation.  So the method of undetermined coefficients (as explained in any ODE textbook) tells you what to do.  Please report what you found in your textbook, do not merely ask us to do it for you!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=y%22%2By%3D4cosx&key=129d2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close! Observe that
$$y_p=2 x\sin(x)$$ satisfies the above, and assuming $y_0=A\cos x+B\sin x,$ the whole solution is known. Check:

$$(2x\sin x)''+2x\sin x=0+2(2x)'(\sin x)'-2x\sin x+2x\sin x=4\cos x$$ Thus $$y= 2x\sin x+C_1\cos x+C_2\sin x \ \diamond$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I realized this a little while ago.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to solve this is by using method of undetermined coefficients.

First, find the complementary solution (the solution to $y''+y=0$). The characteristic polynomial is $$\lambda^2+1=0\Longleftrightarrow \lambda = \pm i$$
Hence, the complementary solution is $$y_c(x)=Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$$
Using euler's identity of $\operatorname{cis}(x)=e^{ix}$ and regrouping terms, we can rewrite the complementary solution into  $$y_c(x) = A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$$

The particular solution assumption for your case (ie $a\cos(x)$) is $y_p(x)=x(m\cos(x)+n\sin(x))$, for constants $m, n$, where we multiply by $x$ to account for the cosine already in the complementary solution.

Why does multiplying by $x$ account for cosine already in the complementary solution? That is because we need both solutions to contain only linearly independent terms.

Any scalar multiple of a term is linearly dependent on that term. Hence, our particular solution's cosine and sine are linearly dependent on the complementary solution's cosine and sine. To make them linearly dependent again, we multiply by a factor of $x$.

So we plug this into our diffeq and we find that  $$-mx\cos(x)-2m\sin(x)+2n\cos(x)-nx\sin(x)+mx\cos(x)+nx\sin(x)=4\cos(x)$$
Simplifying and solving this will result in $m=0, n=2$, so $$y_p(x)=2x\sin(x)$$
Adding these up, we find that the general solution is nothing but $$y(x)=y_c(x)+y_p(x)=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)+2x\sin(x)$$ for some unknown constants $A, B$.